# Convert PHP entities like &ndash; or &scaron; to their original characters in xml file

Tags: php

Actually I displayed mysql data in xml filel.But its showing some special character.how to convert that .this is the example words.

```
                  { ldhe,  world,rdquo  ,Caper,rdquo  }
```

I want to convert to to applicable characters.can you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I just got a similar problem recently.

Got it solved using the combination of [iconv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) and [mb_detect_encoding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php).

Try to parse it to `UTF-8//IGNORE//TRANSLIT`, but `TRANSLIT` will only try to parse char in some similar charsets, and `IGNORE` will discard any char that cannot be found.

One way to do it is like this :

```
$result = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($result), 'UTF-8//IGNORE//TRANSLIT', $result);
```

Comment: hello,I have one more doubt.. if I post any article by writing.It's came nice on browser. If we copy the article from some where and paste that data and  post the data, then the special chrs not converting properly

Comment: Hi, I don't really understand what you mean by that. Can you give me an example?